# UITextField in UITableView not becoming first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I have `UITableView` with about 20 row which each contain a `UITextField`. The first time I tap in a textfield will open the keyboard and I am ready to edit this textfield. If I tap on the next textfield (notice the keyboard is displayed all the time) the keyboard is still displayed but the blue cursor is not in the new textfield and I cannot enter any text. But if I tap on another textfield again, it works just fine. This behavior occurs alternately, one time it works the other time it doesn't.

The  delegate method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` is always called, wether I can edit or not. The delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` is only called when editing works.

This is the code for `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell")!
    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let contentTextField = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! FixableTextField
    contentTextField.delegate = self
    contentTextField.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar

    // Enable/disable editing for text fields
    if isEditing {
        contentTextField.enableEditing()
    } else {
        contentTextField.disableEditing()
    }

    // Present Profile Data
    if profileUpdateBuffer != nil {

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            titleLabel.text = "Count"
            contentTextField.text = "\(profileUpdateBuffer!.count)"
            contentTextField.purposeID = "count"
            contentTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad

        case 1:
            titleLabel.text = "City"
            contentTextField.text = "\(profileUpdateBuffer!.city)"
            contentTextField.purposeID = "city"
            contentTextField.keyboardType = .default

        // ...

        case 20:
            titleLabel.text = "Name"
            contentTextField.text = "\(profileUpdateBuffer!.name)"
            contentTextField.purposeID = "name"
            contentTextField.keyboardType = .default

        default:
            titleLabel.text = ""
            contentTextField.text = ""
        }

        return cell
    }

    // No data available -> show info in first row
    else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            titleLabel.text = "No data"
            contentTextField.text = "No data"
        }
        else {
            titleLabel.text = ""
            contentTextField.text = ""
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

The `enableEditing()` and `disableEditing()` method are from class `FixableTextField`. I can see that the textfields are always enabled because I can see the textfield border

```
// Extract from FixableTextField class
func enableEditing() {
    self.isEnabled = true
    self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
}

func disableEditing() {
    self.isEnabled = false
    self.borderStyle = .none
}
```

Code for the `UITextField`

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    // Delete empty field indicator "-"
    if textField.text == "-" {
        textField.text = ""
    }

    //Move profileTable's contentView to correct position
    if textField is FixableTextField {
        let path = IndexPath(row: rowMap[(textField as! FixableTextField).purposeID]!, section: 0)
        moveContentViewUp(indexPath: path)
    }
    return true
}



func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    // Save new value to profileUpdateBuffer
    do {
        try self.profileUpdateBuffer?.setProperty(value: textField.text!, key: (textField as! FixableTextField).purposeID)
    } catch ProfileError.PropertySettingWrongType {
        let falseInputAlert = UIAlertController(title: "False Input", message: "The input for this field is not valid.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        falseInputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(falseInputAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error when trying to set property for profileUpdateBuffer in ProfileViewController")
    }

    // Display new data in table
    profileTable.reloadData()
}
```

Extract from `setProperty` method which is from class `ProfileData`. `profileUpdateBuffer` is of type `ProfileData`

```
func setProperty(value:String, key:String) throws {
    switch key {
    case "count":
        count = value

    case "city":
        count = value

    // ...

    case "name":
        name = value

    default:
        throw ProfileError.PropertySettingWrongType
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you. Especially your cellForRowAt indexPath function. How do you add listener to your textFields?

Comment: Thanks, of course I will.

Comment: Do you have any filtering logic in 'textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)'? I see you also have your VC set to be the delegate of all your text fields. Do you have a logic to distinguish between cells inside delegate method implementations? You can try moving TextField delegate in the cell so each cell will be responsible for itself.

Comment: Are you always returning `true` in your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. If not, could you post the code?

Comment: Yes I actually have also set an ID for every single textfield in the switch cases (I removed it from the code above) but I don't use it for filtering in textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)

Comment: Imagine this scenario: you have cell 1 and cell 2 with their respective text field 1 (tf1) and text field 2 (tf2). You are editing tf1. Then select tf2. The framework will resign first responder on tf1 and become first responder on tf2. This will trigger shouldBeginEditing for tf2. Now, in response of resigned responder on tf1 the delegate of tf1 will be called with didEndEditing. But you are editing tf2, not tf1! This call will effectively make the tf2 not-editable. Can you add some logs to your code and confirm this is true? If true, try solving this by moving the tf delegate in the cell.

Comment: @mohak Yes, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`always returns true.

Comment: @kr45ko I just did some testing by printing a string in each `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` and `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)` and you are right. I can see that didEnd... is called after shouldBegin every time when I can't edit the textfield (which is every second time). I will add the code for both methods in my question.

Comment: @Codey I wrote a simple program to mimic your issue and think I found the problem. Posted an answer. Hope it will help you fix this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small program to mimic the behavior you describe.
It seems the issue is caused by table view data reloading at the end of your `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    // Save new value to profileUpdateBuffer
    do {
        try self.profileUpdateBuffer?.setProperty(value: textField.text!, key: (textField as! FixableTextField).purposeID)
    } catch ProfileError.PropertySettingWrongType {
        let falseInputAlert = UIAlertController(title: "False Input", message: "The input for this field is not valid.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        falseInputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(falseInputAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error when trying to set property for profileUpdateBuffer in ProfileViewController")
    }

    // Display new data in table
    profileTable.reloadData()
}
```

Try removing `profileTable.reloadData()` for the sake of experiment to confirm the root cause of the problem (yes, your other cells will not be updated).

One way to solve this is by utilizing direct cell updates on `visibleCells` in `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`. I see `profileUpdateBuffer?` is your data model. Just update your cell's titleLabel and textField properties manually from your model if they are in visible cells property of the table view.

If you want to size the cells accordingly, use AutoLayout and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for table view row height combined with `beginUpdates()`/`endUpdates()` calls.

For more details on how to achieve direct cell manipulation and/or dynamic cell size update without loosing the keyboard focus [check the accepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44619293/1867439) I've already answered.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. You were right, when I removed `profileTable.reloadData()` it worked just fine. I fixed it by updating the cells without `realodData` like you said and now everything is ok. Do you have an explanation why this behavior is occurring when using `reloadData`?

Comment: When you start `reloadData()`, the table view is disabling user interaction on itself. The cells will then return false for `becomeFirstResponder()`. In your case the second cell will not become first responder. If you then select a new cell, there is no `reloadData()` call as previous cell did not become first responder thus didEndEditing() (where reloading is located) is not called. This is why the third cell can be edited. I'm not sure why keyboard remains on-screen when editing is not available - I was expecting it to be dismissed when previous text field resigns first responder.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you call profileTable.reloadData()... You should probably only reload one cell. Perhaps textFieldDidEndEditing(*:) gets called with the old TextField as a parameter, followed by textFieldShouldBeginEditing(*:) for the new TextField. The problem is that you refresh all the cells at the end of textFieldDidEndEditing(*:), which means the TextField passed by the system as a parameter to textFieldShouldBeginEditing(*:) may not necessary be the same one that the corresponding cell contains... It may be that those new key-strokes get sent to a TextField belonging to a cell that is in the Queue of reusable cells, i.e. not visible, but still existing somewhere in memory.